# Create PrivateRoute with React-Router-Dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have seen lots of use cases about how people create private route with react-router-dom. 
It usually looks like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, auth:{ isAuthenticated }, ...rest}) =>  (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        isAuthenticated ?
            <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to="/signin" />
    )} />
);
```

And my question is: If I can use this way to do the same thing?

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, auth:{ isAuthenticated }, ...rest }) => (
    isAuthenticated ? <Route {...rest} render={props => <Component {...props}/>}/> :<Redirect to="/signin" />
)
```

It seems working when I ran the code. But I still want to know why we do the condition check at the first way of writing? Is the second way of writing incorrect? If so, why? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a preference thing, either is fine and both will work. you can also make it even shorter and more readable like this if you like

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, auth:{ isAuthenticated }, ...rest }) => (
    isAuthenticated ? <Component {...rest} /> : <Redirect to="/signin" />
)
```

and then render like so:

```
<PrivateRoute
   exact
   component={ComponentToRender}
   path="/path"
   aProp={'aProp'}
/>
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you. :)